# Import an firebase image when i click it in the recyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

What I've done alone so far is to bring up a activity (recyclerView of the products) when I click ImageView 1.

When I click on the image of recyclerView, my goal is to load the image I clicked on ImageView 1 and save it in DB.

How can I get an image?

**this is my product's adapter**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public HolderProductCody onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   //inflate layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_product_seller,parent,false);
   return new HolderProductCody(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderProductCody holder, int position) {
    //get data
    final ModelProduct modelProduct = productList.get(position);
    String id = modelProduct.getProductId();
    String uid = modelProduct.getUid();

    String detailAvailable = modelProduct.getDetailAvailable();
    String productColor = modelProduct.getProductColor();
    String productTpo = modelProduct.getProductTpo();

    String productDescription = modelProduct.getProductDescription();
    String productCategory = modelProduct.getProductCategory();
    String icon = modelProduct.getProductIcon();
    String SeasonCategory = modelProduct.getProductSeasonCategory();
    String productSeasonCategory = modelProduct.getProductSeasonCategory();
    String title = modelProduct.getProductTitle();
    String timestamp = modelProduct.getTimestamp();
    String originalPrice = modelProduct.getOriginalPrice();

    //set data
    holder.titleTv.setText(title);
    holder.SeasonCategoryTv.setText(SeasonCategory);
    holder.tpoTv.setText(productTpo);
    holder.colorTv.setText(productColor);
    holder.originalPriceTv.setText("$"+originalPrice);

    if(detailAvailable.equals("true")){
        //product is on discount
        holder.tpoTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.colorTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else{
        //product is not on discount
        holder.tpoTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.colorTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    try{
        Picasso.get().load(icon).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_tshirt_black).into(holder.productIconIv);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        holder.productIconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tshirt_black);
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //handle item clicks, show item details
            Toast.makeText(context, "클릭됨", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //addcodylayout(modelProduct);
        }
    });



}

private void addcodylayout(ModelProduct modelProduct) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_cody_product,null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();

    //get data
    final String id = modelProduct.getProductId();
    String uid = modelProduct.getUid();
    String detailAvailable = modelProduct.getDetailAvailable();
    String productTpo = modelProduct.getProductTpo();
    String productColor = modelProduct.getProductColor();
    String productDescription = modelProduct.getProductDescription();
    String productCategory = modelProduct.getProductCategory();
    String icon = modelProduct.getProductIcon();
    String productSeasonCategory = modelProduct.getProductSeasonCategory();
    final String title = modelProduct.getProductTitle();
    String timestamp = modelProduct.getTimestamp();
    String originalPrice = modelProduct.getOriginalPrice();

    try{
        Picasso.get().load(icon).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_tshirt_black).into(productIconIv);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        productIconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tshirt_black);
    }
    dialog.show();


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
   if(filter==null){
       filter = new FilterProduct(this,filterList);
   }
    return filter;
}

class HolderProductCody extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    /*holds views of recyclerview*/


    private ImageView productIconIv;
    private TextView tpoTv, titleTv, SeasonCategoryTv,colorTv,originalPriceTv;

    public HolderProductCody(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        productIconIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);
        tpoTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tpoTv);
        titleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        SeasonCategoryTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categorySeasonTv);
        colorTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorTv);
        originalPriceTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.originalPriceTv);
    }
}
```

}

**this is my product's activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cody_product);
    filterProductBtn = findViewById(R.id.filterProductBtn);
    productsRv = findViewById(R.id.productsRv);
    filteredProductsTv = findViewById(R.id.filteredProductsTv);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    filterProductBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CodyProductActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("카테고리 선택").setItems(Constants.productCategories1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //get selected item
                    String selected = Constants.productCategories1[which];
                    filteredProductsTv.setText(selected);
                    if (selected.equals("모든 옷")) {
                        //load all
                        loadAllProducts();
                    } else {
                        //load filtered
                        loadFilteredProducts(selected);
                    }
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
}

private void loadFilteredProducts(String selected) {
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //get all products
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //before getting reset List
            productList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String productCategory = ""+ds.child("productCategory").getValue();
                //if selected category matches product category then add in list
                if(selected.equals(productCategory)){
                    ModelProduct modelProduct = ds.getValue(ModelProduct.class);
                    productList.add(modelProduct);
                }


            }
            //setup adapter
            adapterProductCody = new AdapterProductCody(CodyProductActivity.this,productList);
            //set adapter
            GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(CodyProductActivity.this,3);
            productsRv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            productsRv.setAdapter(adapterProductCody);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseerror) {

        }
    });

}

private void loadAllProducts() {
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //get all products
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //before getting reset List
            productList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelProduct modelProduct = ds.getValue(ModelProduct.class);
                productList.add(modelProduct);
            }
            //setup adapter
            adapterProductCody = new AdapterProductCody(CodyProductActivity.this, productList);
            //set adapter
            GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(CodyProductActivity.this, 3);
            productsRv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            productsRv.setAdapter(adapterProductCody);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

**The ID value of ImageView1 is topImages.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?